# Angular JS confirm password message is already displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two fields password and confirm password and an error message in  tag i.e "password mismatch" but it should be displayed when password is typed incorrectly in confirm password field instead it is already being displaying when I opens the form.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': submitted && CreateClientAdminForm.password.$error.required || CreateClientAdminForm.password.$error.pattern }" >
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password*</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="clientAdmin.User.UserPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20" required  autofocus>
                    <span ng-show="submitted && CreateClientAdminForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password can not be empty</span>

                    <span ng-show="CreateClientAdminForm.password.$error.pattern && CreateClientAdminForm.password.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': submitted && CreateClientAdminForm.confirmpassword.$error.required || CreateClientAdminForm.confirmpassword.$error.pattern }" >
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password*</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="clientAdmin.User.UserconfirmPassword"  ng-pattern="regex.Password" ng-maxlength="20" required  autofocus>
                    <span ng-show="submitted && CreateClientAdminForm.confirmpassword.$error.required" class="help-block">Password can not be empty</span>
                    <span ng-show="clientAdmin.User.UserPassword !== clientAdmin.User.UserconfirmPassword" class="help-block"><p>Password mismatch</p></span>

                    <span ng-show="CreateClientAdminForm.confirmpassword.$error.pattern && CreateClientAdminForm.confirmpassword.$invalid " class="help-block">Please enter a valid password with at least 6 characters. </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller

```
    globalWeAlertApp.controller("ClientAdminController", function($scope, ClientAdminService,UserCRUDService, toastr, $cookieStore, $window ) {

              //Other functions

    }
```

Comment: You can try checking if `confirmpassword` input field is dirty then the other condition.

Comment: Yes, use `ng-if` to implement it

Comment: Sorry I did not get can you please elaborate how can check that?

Comment: what are the default values of clientAdmin.User.UserPassword and clientAdmin.User.UserconfirmPassword? How have you initialised them in your controllers?

Comment: It a json what actually i want post in field of password i.e 
$scope.data = {
                "CreateClientAdminRequest": {
                    "CMMHeader": {
                        "ClientUserName": $scope.clientAdmin.User.username,
                        "ClientPassword": $scope.clientAdmin.User.password
                    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span
ng-show="clientAdmin.User.UserPassword != clientAdmin.User.UserconfirmPassword
&& (clientAdmin.User.UserPassword != '' &&
lientAdmin.User.UserconfirmPassword != '' )" 
class="help-block">
<p>Password mismatch</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Worked! ^_^ Thanks